# Stack and Generic Types (jagged arrays)

Tags: c#, arrays, static, stack, jagged-arrays

- OK, im making a Stack whit array. But I need to Push Arrays in the Stack like a jagged Array.
- Problem: No valid Arguments.

**Method Push:**

```
 public bool Push(T [] dato, int tamanio2)
    {
        if(tope==max)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Imposible ingresar datos, la pila esta llena");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Arreglo[tope] = dato[tamanio2];
            tope++;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**Main:**

```
Cpila < string [] > pila = new Cpila< string[] >(10);

        string [] Nombres = new string [5] {"Carlos","Jose", "Patricio","Pedro","Andres"};
        pila.Push(Nombres,5);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I need to pass the initialized array in the main , to the method Push but it gives me an error

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the code fully here, but what I can point out from my knowledge of C# here, is that when you have this code -
`Cpila < string [] > pila = new Cpila< string[] >(10);`
You are essentially saying that the Type parameter T = string[]

Then you have method `public bool Push(T [] dato, int tamanio2)`, i.e. substituting the type parameter `public bool Push(string[][] dato, int tamanio2)`

Now when you call the method push.. like so `pila.Push(Nombres,5);` you are passing Numbers, which is `string[]`, and not `string[][]`

Hope this helps you fix your code..